# Orbix client in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, corba

Is there an easy way to create an [Orbix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbix) client in Delphi 7? The server is created in C and runs on a Linux server.

I know about idl2pas.bat but does that not generate Visibroker specific stubs? It looks like the generated code links to CORBA.pas which loads the "orbpasxx.dll".

Basically I need to know what the minimum steps would be to create such a client.

Answer (score 2):

A guide of getting started with [Orbix (for C++)](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/gen3/33/html/orbix33cxx_pguide/GettingStartedCxx.html) but some of the ideas would be similar. (I think)

Another article relating to [Delphi](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10343), from embarcadero. Or maybe [this article](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/gen3/33/html/orbixcomet33_pguide/getstarted.html)

Apologies, if these are not helpful.

Good Luck with your problem!!!